# Is it okay to declare the db instance as a global variable for accessible at all the time , without need to use "require" statement in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in "node js"
I am developing an program and I want to use the database model in all
**For example (something like "wpdb") WordPress**
Is the best way to create it as a global variable, or to use the `require` statement as needed?

Please help me get the best answer.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the best way to handle a db connection. You only want the db open and around for as long as necessary and no longer. Usually this means opening the db connection at the place in your code that can know how long to keep it open and then close the connection after using it.

If you are simply referring to the configuration for opening a DB connection, then you could define that configuration object at application start and then pass it as a parameter to your db instantiation code.

```
import myUserDbCode from '../myUserDbFile';
import myUserMessagesCode from '../myUserMsgsDbFile';

const dbConfig = {
  dbname: 'myFancyDb',
  serverName: 'myDbServerName',
  connectionTimeout: 60
}

(async () => {

  const userList = await myUserDbCode(dbConfig)
    .then((dbResultSet) => {
      return dbResultSet.data;
    }
  };

  const myUser = userList[42];

  const userMessages = await myUserMessagesCode(dbConfig, myUser)
    .then((dbResultSet) => {
      return dbResultSet.data;
    }
  };

  console.log(userMessages);
})();
```

I recommend following some DB tutorials that show how to build a complete application to see some patterns about how to handle passing configuration options to code and how to manage DB connections.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I want to put them in separate files
@kevintechie

Comment: What do you mean by them? If you're referring to the db code, you have to use modules and export the methods and then import (require) them before calling them, but the passing of the config is the same. Again, you should follow a DB tutorial in an app context to see how to organize your code and pass data between modules.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more basic information about how to structure and import your code.

Comment: If you are new to Node, it's very important to understand modules so you can organize (modularize) your code. Here is a [basic tutorial and description of modules](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-modules) in node. The local module section describes what's going on in my sample code. Here I put each call in its own file, but you could organize all the user db access in the same file and then call the exported methods like myUserDb.myUserMessagesCode(dbConfig, myUser) similar to how log is handled in the example.